# "undefined" passing data attribute with rails objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to use jquery .click function to detect when to show content. The content that I want displayed after click is passed to a link in a data attribute, like so:

```
== link_to "show", "#", class: "content", id: "content_name", data: {docs: products.limit(10)}
```

then in my application.js file i catch the click, like so:

```
$('.content').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = $('#content_name').data('docs');
      alert(data);
}) //missing ')' here
```

In the end I end up with undefined in attempt to see objects.

Comment: check the generated html

Comment: you are missing  `)` is it typo?

Comment: it's not a typo, it works with regular strings. ex. alert('hello world') works.

Comment: Yeah I'm not seeing a missing `)`, @guradio did you add it in your edit?

Comment: @azium yes i did is it wrong pls correct the update if it is wrong

Comment: @guradio all good, you probably don't need the comment though, just correcting it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.content').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $('#content_name').data('docs');
  alert(data);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
e.preventDefualt();
```

To:

```
e.preventDefault();
```